# Exclude files by wildcard through Tortoise SVN shell menu

Tags: tortoisesvn, file-extension

I am using Tortoise SVN 1.6.16 in Windows 7. If I have a certain file type I want to exclude from future commits, I thought I could just go find a file of that type within my working folder, then right click it, and select "TortoiseSVN->Delete and Add to Ignore List->*.ext" where ext is the file extension of the file I clicked, as shown in the image below.

However, when I do this, it only excludes that specific file, and the next time I commit, all other files of that type still come up in the list to commit.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I just tell Tortoise or SVN to ignore all files of a certain type from future commits?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same hunch as @Stefan: that you were probably seeing files in subdirectories and thinking those should have also been ignored even though you only applied the ignore to a single folder.

So if that is in fact the case, here is the recipe:

**When you want to ignore files or patterns from a single directory:**

Use the convenience menu command to add to the ignore list.

**When you want to ignore files or patterns from a subtree:**

Open the subversion properties (`TortoiseSVN >> Properties`) of the root of the subtree. Add or edit an entry for the `svn:ignore` keyword. The illustration shows an example where I have specified to ignore an `obj` subfolder as well as all files with a `.user` or `.bak` extension.

[image]

The secret, though, is in the specification--when you define the patterns to ignore, select the recursive choice as indicated here:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is one catch to this method: In my example, I had previously specified to ignore `obj` and `*.user` and I was adding just the `*.bak` pattern. When I apply recursively, it does not apply just the *change* (*.bak) but *everything* in the svn:ignore keyword (obj, *.user, and *.bak) to all subfolders. That may or may not be what you want, so be aware of it.

Comment: OK, I tried this and it looks like it will do what I want. Unfortunately, when I applied to ignore a few file types, the new svn:ignore entry replaced the old one, which had some more detailed exclusions (specific files). Is there any way to have multiple ignore propoerties so you can have a combination of global (within the working folder) and specific file exclusions?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more explicit: `svn:ignore` keywords for all subfolders below your selected folder will be overwritten with the new set you are applying. So this technique is not a panacea for all situations.

Answer (score 2):

It ignores all bat files right, but not recursively! It only ignores them in the folder you added it to the ignore list.

Comment: Gotcha. Is there an easy way to make it ignore them for the entirety of the current working directory? If not, does it at least take into account sub-folders so I could make a file of the type I want to exclude in the root of the working folder and exclude that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Tortoise's global ignore pattern (if it's applicable to all your working copies):

- TortoiseSVN -> Settings
- General
- Fill out the "Global ignore pattern" field, such as adding "*.ext" at the end of it, separating entries with a space.